# Как зафиксировать язык клавиатуры на английский для UITextField на iOS?

Tags: ios, email, клавиатура, ввод, uitextfield

У меня есть `TextField`, в котором я должен ввести адрес электронной почты. Кириллица в адресе почты запрещена, поэтому я хочу убрать возможность смены языка для этого `TextField`'a.

Comment: Вопрос хороший. Только возможно это не нужно именно в вашем приложении, потому что и гмейл и яндекс поддерживают кириллицу в емейлах. Ну скажем, глеб.калачёв@почта.рф )